# How to revert a Lenovo notebook to factory settings?

Tags: operating-systems, formatting, lenovo-laptop, factory-defaults

Given a Lenovo notebook where the hard drive has been formated completely. How can I get it back to factory settings? Can I get the Lenovo bloatware version of Windows 8 anywhere?

Comment: You need recovery disc with bootloader. If the HDD is completely empty, that's the only way to do it. See if your warranty/extended warranty covers any support. Ask lenovo to send you something which you can write to a disc and load it onto your target machine. I assume you don't even have the recovery partition? Usually for Ideapad V470, I get the setup option @F12 keypress.

Comment: @hagubear Right, I don't have the recovery partition. Technically, there is everything alright with the machine. It runs a Linux installation. But I have to send it in that's why I need to revert it to factory setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the support and it turns out that they don't expect the Lenovo OEM version to be installed. You can even send your device in with a formatted disk without installed operating system. They will install it on their own if needed to find or fix the problem.

However, if someone is interested in getting the recovery partition back, you can order a disk at [Lenovo Recovery](http://www.lenovorecovery.com).

Answer (score 1):

Unless where you got it from has the Software that came with the laptop, your best bet is to get in contact with Lenovo and request the software from them for your laptop - Including the OS and other software they install.

I haven't done this with Lenovo but when I requested software for my laptop from Dell they where more then happy to do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I contacted the support and they were really welcoming.